# How to set javadoc path for a jar in a project using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar, classpath, javadoc

I'm using JUnit 3 in Eclipse Galileo. The `junit.jar` (located in the project in `vendor/lib/`) contains both the classes and the javadoc. In my project which I share using CVS, I want the doc to be available for everybody who checks-out the project. So I committed the `.classpath` file. 
When adding the javadoc path to the lib using the Eclipse UI I get the following classpath entry:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="vendor/lib/junit.jar">
  <attributes>
    <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="jar:platform:/resource/MyProject/vendor/lib/junit.jar!/javadoc"/>
  </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

Note that "MyProject" is the local name of the Project. This name is not necessarily the same for each person on the team (also I have multiple local copies, which must have different names). So this classpath entry is not portable from one copy of the project to another.

What I want to achieve is a javadoc location which is only relative to the project (as is the `lib` files location for example).

I tried the following without success:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="vendor/lib/junit.jar">
  <attributes>
    <attribute name="javadoc_location" value="jar:file:vendor/lib/junit.jar!/javadoc"/>
  </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

How should I set the classpath entry so that the javadoc is taken from a jar in the project without reference to the platform or external location?

Answer (score 2):

May be you have to place the folder "MyProject" to CVS so that everyone will get same folder name.

My understanding, a big project usually contains many eclipse projects and we often put them together in one folder. like:

```
+trunk/
  + MyProject
     + module1
     + module2
     + .....
     + modulen
  + YourProject
     + yourModule1
     + yourModule2
     + .....
     + yourModulen
```

It works fine to me until now.

Comment: The problem is, that when you checkout the project multiple times you must choose in Eclipse different names for each checkout (eg. MyProject1, MyProject2). Eclipse uses this name as a folder name and thus the path to the javadoc is different for each checkout.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, if your jar file is not in the root of the project, you must use an absolute path to reference it.  If you would like to use a relative path to the project, you might have to consider moving the jar file to the root of the project.

HTH,
Jc